# How much of a gamble was The Lord of the Rings trilogy?

Tags: production, the-lord-of-the-rings

It still feels astounding to me that a studio would green-light a 3 film fantasy series to be shot back to back, especially with a then relatively unproven producer-director in Peter Jackson.

Of course the film landscape was very different twenty years ago, the books were (and continue to be) a fantasy staple and the budget for the whole thing wasn't really that much when seen by today's standards ($281 million, according to Wikipedia).

But still, surely, there must have been worries.
**Was there anything that helped put the studio at ease that this was going to turn out alright?

Or some manner of extenuating circumstance particular to this project?**

(I vaguely recall some of this being alluded to in the bonus features of the three films, but that was years ago and there's so much of it)

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss this as Primarily Opinion-Based just yet. If I remember right Jackson did have a bumpy start with Miramax, King King, book rights, and original production costs. There might be some evidence to show/suggest it was a gamble from the start or evidence to show why New Line Cinema execs chose to invest in at least the first film out there, somewhere...

Comment: @DarthLocke I recall the story goes that PJ went to New Line asking them to finance two films and they were given a three film deal instead. All three films were filmed simultaneously so there was never an option to only invest in the first film.

Comment: That's probably right, as I said, "invest in at least", because I might not member all of the details accurately. I'm just saying there might be info out there, one way or another, to help factually answer the Q.